# UK Marriage visitor visa after marriage and change of passport

Tags: visas, uk, passport-renewals, weddings

I am planning to marry my fiance in the UK. He is a British citizen living in the UK, and I am a Turkish citizen living in Germany. I will apply for the marriage visitor visa. However, we are trying to figure out two things for timing and procedural issues:

- Can I use the marriage visitor visa to re-enter to the UK after the marriage (until it expires)?
- When I change my passport due to marriage (changing maiden surname), would I still be able to use my marriage visitor visa on my old passport?

I know this is a complex situation. I will appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 6):

A marriage visa allows someone to enter the UK only for the purpose of getting married. It is explicitly only for someone who is not planning on settling in the UK after marriage.

Because it is for the purpose of getting married, you cannot use it after you are married. You can remain for a short period after you are married, but not re-enter the UK. The purpose of the visa has been fulfilled.

Since the visa cannot be reused the question about your name change is irrelevant.